# Loop through table containing checkboxes and update MySQL (PHP server side)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Disclaimer**: Apologies for the repeated question, but I could not adapt similar examples which I found so far to my need. Mainly because I am just starting with web programming languages by myself and I lack of basic understanding of the subject.

**What I want do do:**
Create a web page which selects data from a MySql db and dumps the output in a HTML table. In the db table there is one field of Boolean type, which in the browser I want it to be displayed as Checkboxes (checked or not according to the table records)

So far so good...

Then I want the user to be able to change each checkbox and save the values updating the db table back, and this is the part I am struggling with. Apparently I need to use AJAX to POST and data into the server, execute my php there to update the db and get a response of whether it succeeded or not. Yet, I am not managing to understand and apply the concept myself.

My table created with php during the page load and the button which I want to click to update the db:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="ctrlbutton" id="clear" value="Clear All"><input type="button" class="ctrlbutton" id="save" value="Save">
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <th id="id">id</th>
        <th id="item">item</th>
        <th id="category">category</th>
        <th id="status">status</th>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Belt</td><td>Clothes</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="ctrlcb"checked/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Flip-Floaps</td><td>Clothes</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="ctrlcb"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Pants / Shorts</td><td>Clothes</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="ctrlcb"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

A Jquery script which I was planning to use to detect which checkboxes are checked in order to build the query statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function GetSelectedIDs(){
    $('#save').on('click', function GetSelectedIDs() {
        $('input:checked').each(function GetSelectedIDs() {
            var $checked = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:has(input))");
            console.log($checked);
            return $checked;
        });
    });
});
```

The php functions where I plan to call to escape the SQL statement (again, I understand it should be done but I not convinced if I am doing it right) and the function to update the DB based on the SQL str.

```
function db_sqlquote($value) {
    $connection = db_connect();
    return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";
}
    function db_query($query) {

    $connection = db_connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    return $result;
}
```

Whatever best practice I am skipping or any feedback you can give me will be appreciated.

If matters I am using WAMP and writing my code in Notepad++, not sure if it is good approach though.

Comment: Your code potentially is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. Using mysqli_real_escape_string is not safe in all circumstances. It's not really the intended purpose of that function to protect against injection attacks.

Comment: meanwhile you've missed out all the bits where you submit the data via ajax, and receive the submitted parameters into PHP in order to send them to the DB. Is that what you're struggling with? Have you taken any introductory tutorials on this topic? It should explain the basic structure that you need.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks a lot for your answer. You are right, the part I am struggling with is the AJAX part. To put in detailed steps:

1. Take to output of the Jquery I posted and translate that into a SQL update statement.
2. Call the PHP function via AJAX.
3. Get a response confirming that the db got updated.

Yes, I found similar topics and tried to check at W3Schools for basic AJAX examples but I did not succeed to translate them into something that actually worked in my case.